# Changing ChildOf constraint influence to 0, but keeping the position it had as a child

Tags: animation, constraints

I had a sword object rigged with a single bone, with a ChildOf constraint making it a child of a sheath (with an influence of 1). Throughout an animation i move the sheath, and the sword bone follows as expected.

However, i cant seem to lower the influence of the sheath to zero and still have the sword retain the position it was just at, and I am wondering how i should go about making this happen.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think this is sort of a bug or issue, I noticed that too, even when you toggle off the constraint eye icon. You may consider to report [here](https://developer.blender.org/)

Comment: @Leon Cheung As far as I am aware this is just standard behaviour for objects that are constrained.

Comment: @RayMairlot You mean a constraint can still take effect even if being disabled?

Comment: @LeonCheung I meant that it is standard that turning a constraint's influence to zero returns the object to it's pre-constrained position. If if a constraint is turned off and it still affects the object, then yes, it may be a bug or a refresh issue due to depsgraph limitations.

Comment: Here is a video about it that I made: https://youtu.be/O6hL1Haj_A8

Answer (score 8):

This has been built into Blender since version 2.80. Just click the "Disable and Keep Transform" button next to the influence slider.

See [the 2.80 release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Animation#Constraints) for more info.

Comment: Though, it is not animatable, isn't it?

Comment: The button performs an action. It is not animatable in the same way that "File Save" is not animatable. You can press the button, and then animate the influence slider, though.

Answer (score 7):

The trick to unparenting is to animate the constraint and the objects location. On one frame you keyframe the objects location using Insert visual locrotscale, the **visual keying options** will keyframe values **after modifiers and constraints are applied**. You also key the constraint influence as 1.0 on this frame. Then move one frame and keyframe the childof influence as 0.0.

After you keyframe the visual location and change the constraint to 0.0 the object will snap back to it's original position. Once you keyframe the influence go back a frame and it will go back to where the keyframes put it.

You may also have two constraints, one parenting to the sheath and another parenting to the hand. You just have one at 0.0 influence and the other at 1.0 influence on one frame and swap them around the next frame.

[image]

Sample blend[image]

Answer (score 3):

For dynamic parenting use the [Dynamic Parent](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Animation/Dynamic_Parent) addon. It does what you want well and fast.

Basically you need to keyframe your sword transforms, but this addon will do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

- Parent the child with a *Child Of* constraint (here sphere parented to cube), click on the *Set Inverse* button so that your object stay at its current position.

[image]

- Move the parent (here from frame 0 to 20).

[image]

- The frame before the dropping is supposed to happen, let say frame 9, select the child and <kbd>i</kbd> > create a *LocRotScale* keyframe.

[image]

- Also, at the same frame, <kbd>i</kbd> > create a keyframe on the *Child Of* constraint *Influence*, with its factor at 1.

[image]

- The frame where the dropping is supposed to happen, here frame 10, select the child and this time <kbd>i</kbd> > create a *Visual LocRotScale* keyframe.

[image]

- For the *Child Of* constraint, set the *Influence* factor at 0 and <kbd>i</kbd> > create a keyframe. It should work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made this screenshot of a tutorial I found regarding this issue (unfortunately I forgot the creator's name). Works like a charm!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little add-on for this, to help a colleague at the Blender Institute with this exact issue (disabling a constraint without moving the constrained object). It's at my [Random Blender Add-ons repository](https://github.com/sybrenstuvel/random-blender-addons/blob/master/disable_constraint_without_moving.py). It also has operators for copying and pasting matrices (in world coordinates).

Comment: Just wanted to update this answer link to the [Random Blender Addons](https://github.com/sybrenstuvel/random-blender-addons)

Comment: Thanks. The add-on is no longer necessary since I moved the functionality into Blender itself. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/204165/888