# Is it possible to parent an object to a different bone in 2 different (multiple) animation?

Tags: bones, parent, dopesheet

I'm doing multiple animation on a humanoid who has some kind of a sword carrier (I don't knonw the exact word). And so this sword carrier AND the sword are both parented to a leg bone , but only for the walk and run animation.
So I'd like to know if there is a way to clear the parent of the leg bone and parent it to the hand bone but only for the attack animation.
Hope you understood what I'm searching for and that you can answer me :D

P.S. : I already tried the 'child of' technique, but that get me to another problem of position between the animation.[image]

Comment: Can you provide a test .blend file to troubleshoot the problem on? It is hard to guess what the problem might be.

Comment: [This answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24591/935) may help.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution is the Child_Of constraint if you want to alter parenting in pose mode. If that leads to another problem, ask it, there is probably solution to it.

Make sure the bone that is gonna get the Child_Of constraint has no parents. Else you will get multiple parent transformations (the original parent and the constraint on top).

There is a way to rig an inverse parent transformation to negate the original parent (if present) when needed from pose mode, but it is complicated and probably not worth it.

Comment: In fact the "other problem" is that if I try to fix the Child _of constraint by simply add a keyframe of LocRotScale on my sword ( which will be different in the 2 animaions) it also change the LotRotScale of my armature and I can't understand why.