# Object child of two parents

Tags: animation, bones, constraints

Imagine this scenario. Crane 1 picks up a boulder and puts it into a cart, the cart moves, stops and then the boulder gets picked up by Crane 2.

Armature wise everything works. I'm having difficulty transferring the object

My issue is:

Boulder is child of a bone in crane 1 using constraints. it gets moved by the animation but I can't get the crane to "release" the boulder. Setting the influence to 0 leaves the object where it was before it was picked up.

I can get round this with 3 scenes, but I want to just use 1 in a continuous flowing animation

Whats the proper way to do this?

Thank you in advance for any help
Sean

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24581/changing-childof-constraint-influence-to-0-but-keeping-the-position-it-had-as-a/24591#24591)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this...

[image]

...you can animate the ***Visibility*** of three ***Copy Transform Constraints*** (Multiple *Child Of* constraints will not work) on your Boulder, one for each crane and cart:

[image]

The only trick is, *at the end*, you must keyframe the transforms by performing a ***Copy All To Selected*** on the Boulder.  This will keep it at it's final resting spot.  Then simply remove visibility of all constraints:

[image]

[image]