# How do I move one bone together with each other

Tags: animation

I am making a reload animations and the clip is not moving with hand in the timeline. How do I fix this I have restarted many times. Here is a picture[image]

Comment: You can [animate the influence of a child of constraint](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24591/935) to control when the clip follows the hand.

Comment: I am sorry but i did not get what the tutorial was saying please explain better thank you!

Comment: A child follows the parent. A [childof constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/relationship/child_of.html) gives you parenting with an influence value that can be animated. This allows you to parent the clip to the hand when you want to remove a clip, then disable it when you want the clip to stick to the gun.