# Is it possible to keyframe parenting/constraints?

Tags: animation, objects, transforms, keyframes

I made a robot and I want a part from his body to move from one place to somewhere else while he is walking (from his back, over his shoulder, to the chest)

My question is; how do I attach the part on his back so it stays on there while moving, and unattach it to move it to the chest, and then attach it there mid-animation?

I can do the moving of the part itself by just keyframing it to that spot, but how do I unattach and re-attach it to his chest so that it moves along with the chest from that point?

Comment: use **child of** constraint and keyframe the influence

Comment: [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24581/changing-childof-constraint-influence-to-0-but-keeping-the-position-it-had-as-a)